# Obj-C: How to make a cache without keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, caching

I'm trying to make a cache of objects to reuse on-demand.

It is sort of like the UITableViewCell mechanism. When I need a new object I'll get one from the pool (I don't care which one), and if there's none available I'll create a new one to put into the cache. When I'm done with it I'll put it back into the pool for later use.

NSCache is the most similar class I know of, but it's a key/value cache, so it's not exactly what I have in mind. I don't care which object the cache give me, I want to just get one (any one) from the cache, use it, then put it back when I'm done.

So what should I use for this kind of mechanism?

Edit: it doesn't have to be from iOS framework. I'm open for external open source libraries too.

Edit 2: I'll put an example to clarify: 
Suppose I'm trying to create an ant nest (the cache): there's some 10000 ants inside the nest.

- When I need food I'll grab one of the ants and tell it to go out and get food (the ant is removed from the cache). I don't care which ant does the job because they're all ants to me. When its task is done, the ant will come back to the nest and stay there until I give it a new order.
- In case my nest has run out of ant for any reason (the cache is empty), I'll tell the ant queen to breed some more.
- In case the nest is running out of resources (received memory warning) I want the excessive ants to die by itself (auto memory management similar to NSCache).
- If there's no resource crisis the ants can stay where it is and wait for my order (I am a generous god).

Comment: It sounds like you already have a good idea of what's required. I'd convert the ant story into some pseudo code and then implement that. Definitely sounds like you are on the right track to me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want is not a cache, but a queue. Keep a reuse queue and dequeue an object from it, or enqueue an element for reuse. An NSArray is sufficient.

Comment: @PhineasLue the reason I called it a cache is simply because I really want the features of [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html) for my pool (please check the first 2 bullet points in the link). Especially the first point. Simply removing items in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` should suffice, but I hope to be as tight as possible on memory here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSCache. But you don't want to deal with keys of NSCache.

So Ant class is subclass of NSObject. Use NSMutableSet to hold `hash` of every Ant. See *NSObject Protocol Reference* for `hash` method.

Use `anyObject` to dequeue and `addObject:` to enqueue hash value from NSMutableSet. Use hash as parameter to NSCache `objectForKey:`.

This only saves memory if Ant objects in total are larger than an NSMutableSet of NSUIntegers.

This seems easier than trying to create a customized NSMutableSet class with NSCache's thread-safety and auto-removal.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. I have been testing your solution for the past few days and it does seem to fit my needs, so cheers, thanks :)